# Sequence of tenses in object clauses

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> One member of the parliament said that the fee will encourage people
>   to use reusable cups. ([Here](https://www.newsinlevels.com/products/the-uks-latte-levy-level-2/))

Why is the future tense used in the object clause (instead of the future in the past form)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *One member of the parliament **said** that the fee **would** encourage people to use reusable cups.*

The use of ***would*** in this case is always correct.

However, this is a news story, which means that the time of the member of the parliament saying is still a recent event, albeit in the past. In cases like this, using ***will*** instead of ***would*** is also correct.